# java.lang.illegalStateException randomly occurs when getting mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition

Tags: java, android

This code works fine song play perfectly but some time randomly going to next song manually crashes application. Happens randomly

```
    updateSeekBar = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int runtime = mediaPlayer.getDuration();
            int currentPosition = 0;
            while (currentPosition < runtime) {
                try {
                    sleep(500);
                    currentPosition = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();//This is where the app crash                        
                    if (seekBar != null) {
                        seekBar.setProgress(currentPosition);
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }
    };
```

Crash report

```
06-10 22:08:53.160 15351-15560/skydeveloper.me.musicx2 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-6875
                                                                     Process: skydeveloper.me.musicx2, PID: 15351
                                                                     java.lang.IllegalStateException
                                                                         at android.media.MediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition(Native Method)
                                                                         at skydeveloper.me.musicx2.Player$1.run(Player.java:104)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16405594/what-is-this-error-java-lang-illegalstateexception-at-mediaplayer-getcurrentposi

Comment: post the full stacktrace please

Comment: @petey update question

Comment: @Akash can you share your mediaplayer initialization code?

Comment: the media player can only give that error for getCurrentPosition() if it happens to be in the error state (see table here - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html ) add an error listener and see if it returns any error

Comment: That's because you try to play media player after it has stopped and seems there are the wrong on initialization. So please share your full media player initialization code so we can figure out the problem.

Comment: @ikhsan `mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), uri);
        mediaPlayer.start();`

Answer (score 6):

Actually this problem occurs if Media player is in wrong state.

If your MediaPlayer is in the `Initialized-State`, you cannot call `start()`. So you have to wait till your MediaPlayer is in the `Prepared-State` position.
**You can only seek the Mediaplayer in Prepared, Started and Paused State.**

For more details you can check: [Media Player State Diagram](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html)

You can also make second call for current position. As it is random issue then bypassing and again calling the method can save you.

```
mediaPlayer.reset();

try {
   .......
   .......
   currentPosition = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
   ......
} catch (IllegalStateException e) {
   mediaPlayer.reset();
   currentPosition = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
}

mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
```

Resource Link:
[What is this error java.lang.IllegalStateException at MediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16405594/what-is-this-error-java-lang-illegalstateexception-at-mediaplayer-getcurrentposi)

---

---

### UPDATE1:

You can bypass the exception and make a second call by using it. Hope it may help you.

```
try {
....
currentPosition = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
....
} catch (final Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    if (e instanceof IllegalStateException) { // bypass IllegalStateException
        .......
        // You can again call the method and make a counter for deadlock situation or implement your own code according to your situation
        if (retry) {
               mediaPlayer.reset();
               currentPosition = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
        } else {
            throw e;
        }
    }
}
```

### UPDATE2:

This will try 3 times to get current position. If not found, then it will give exception.

```
 try {
     ....
     currentPosition = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
     ....
     } catch (final Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
         if (e instanceof IllegalStateException) { // bypass IllegalStateException
             .......
             // You can again call the method and make a counter for deadlock situation or implement your own code according to your situation
             boolean checkAgain = true;
             int counter = 0;
                 for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
                     if (checkAgain) {
                         mediaPlayer.reset();
                         currentPosition = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
                         if(currentPosition > 0) {
                             checkAgain = false;
                             counter++;
                         }
                     } else {
                         if(counter == 0){
                             throw e;
                         }
                     }
                 }


         }
     }
```

### UPDATE4:

1. An `IllegalStateException` is thrown if `prepare()` or `prepareAsync()` is
   called in any other state.
2. While in the Prepared state, properties such as audio/sound volume,
   screenOnWhilePlaying, looping can be adjusted by invoking the
   corresponding set methods.
3. To start the playback, `start()` must be called. After `start()` returns
   successfully, the MediaPlayer object is in the Started state.
   **isPlaying() can be called to test whether the MediaPlayer object is
   in the Started state.**
4. While in the Started state, the internal player engine calls a user
   supplied `OnBufferingUpdateListener.onBufferingUpdate()` callback
   method if a OnBufferingUpdateListener has been registered beforehand
   via `setOnBufferingUpdateListener(OnBufferingUpdateListener)`. This
   callback allows applications to keep track of the buffering status
   while streaming audio/video. Calling `start()` has not effect on a
   MediaPlayer object that is already in the Started state.

So `isPlaying()` method should be checked. So code will be look like below:

```
 try {
     ....
     currentPosition = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
     ....
     } catch (final Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
         if (e instanceof IllegalStateException) { // bypass IllegalStateException
             .......
             // You can again call the method and make a counter for deadlock situation or implement your own code according to your situation
             boolean checkAgain = true;
             int counter = 0;
                 for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
                     if (checkAgain) {
                         mediaPlayer.reset();
                         if(mediaPlayer != null & mediaPlayer.isPLaying()) {
                            currentPosition = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
                         } else {
                            currentPosition = 0; 
                         }
                         if(currentPosition > 0) {
                             checkAgain = false;
                             counter++;
                         }
                     } else {
                         if(counter == 0){
                             throw e;
                         }
                     }
                 }


         }
     }
```

Comment: I am calling `getCurrentPosition()` method after calling `start()` method. I tried you example above i am getting same exception in catch block at `mediaPlayer.reset();`

Comment: @AkashKumar I have updated the answer. Would you please check and let me know if is there any update?

Comment: Didn't get the if(retry) part whats the retry?

Comment: retry means that you can again call the method and make a counter for deadlock situation or implement your own code according to your situation @AkashKumar

Comment: @AkashKumar Would you please check UPDATE2 portion? I have just updated.

Comment: @AkashKumar `isPlaying()` method should be checked. So check the updated4 portion.

Answer (score 3):

In this code checks to see if the current position is before the end, and if so it waits 500ms, by which time it might be past the end! In fact for all practical purposes, it might reach the end just a moment after the check. This is not thread safe but there are synchronization solutions to mitigate this condition. I would suggest you use a simpler solution like this:

```
updateSeekBar = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int runtime = mediaPlayer.getDuration();
            int currentPosition = 0;
            int adv = 0;
            while ((adv = ((adv = runtime - currentPosition) < 500)?adv:500) > 2) {
                try {
                    currentPosition = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
                    if (seekBar != null) {
                        seekBar.setProgress(currentPosition);
                    }
                    sleep(adv);    
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    seekBar.setProgress(runtime);
                    break;
                }

            }
        }
    };
```

This code first calculates the difference between the currentPosition and the duration and only if there is more than 2ms difference it will try to get the new current position (2ms is just an arbitrary number to add some safety margin while sacrificing 2ms of accuracy at the end.) Also sleep is moved to the end of the loop, which adds to the safety margin and also makes the display of the seekbar more inline with the current position. Lastly there is a catch statement added just in case everything else fails.

By the way, while it is not shown in your code, I am assuming seekBar is final so there is no need to check for null every time. Maybe move it to the top and exit if it is null.

Answer (score 2):

It may be possible, when you try to get the position of media player at that time player has stopped or released, so apply below conditions for that,

```
     if(mediaPlayer != null & mediaPlayer.isPLaying())
        currentPosition = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
     else 
        currentPosition = 0;
```

try below code,

```
     handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int runtime = mediaPlayer.getDuration();
            int currentPosition = 0;
            while (currentPosition < runtime) {
               try {
                    if(mediaPlayer != null & mediaPlayer.isPLaying())
                        currentPosition = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
                    else 
                       currentPosition = 0;    

                    if (seekBar != null) {
                          seekBar.setProgress(currentPosition);
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
              }
          }
      }, 500);
```

Comment: Now it crash in if condition at mediaPlayer.isPlaying() with same error

Comment: ok then it is confirm that as you are calling this method in thread which is not UI thread and therefore it is crashing your application, so try to write your code in UI thread or handler and it will work properly.

Comment: Do i need to start handler? This code doesn't update seekBar

Comment: Actually by handler.postDelayed() it should start and perform operation, but if it is not working then first check currentPosition value as if it is 0 then also it will not update seekbar and if it is not then you need to start it.

Comment: Actually i am not able to interact with application at all once this `handler.postDelayed()` start. Shows app not responding on trying to interact with app.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the reason for this is the **thread**.sleep() line. it causes the current thread to sleep while the media player can be actually in a stopped or released state.

The docs mention that calling **getCurrentPosition()** must happen at one of the **valid** states:

> {Idle, Initialized, Prepared, Started, Paused, Stopped,
>   PlaybackCompleted}

Before calling getCurrentPosition, you can check that the media player is actually playing by checking [isPlaying()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#isPlaying()) value.

Also you can run your thread using a [Timer](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html) and a [TimerTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask.html) instead of using while loops and Thread.sleep();

Comment: if check if mediaPlayer.isPlaying than app crash at mediaPlayer.isPlaying. I will check Timer and TimerTask.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly suspect that these methods are not thread safe. Even with the state checking that people are suggesting, you may still run into a problem if you interleave another operation from a different thread that renders this check useless.

Consider synchronizing on the media player object to prevent concurrent access. You'll have to declare the mediaPlayer to be final.

```
final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = ...
```

And later (with one of the suggested checks. I didn't look to see if this was the appropriate one):

```
synchronized (mediaPlayer) {
  if (mediaPlayer != null & mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
    currentPosition = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
  } else {
    currentPosition = 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the state diagram:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qnX4K.gif)

You will realize that you should call reset() to get it back to the idle state. Only then can you call setDataSource()

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
replace the `mMediaPlayer.start();` with this:

```
mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                    mMediaPlayer.start();
                }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

By making my custom mediaPlayer state (based of state diagram) , I was able to call getCurrentPosition() method without any exception.
For my audio Player, I created below states.

```
private enum class MediaPlayerState {
    IDLE,
    PLAYING,
    PAUSED,
    COMPLETED,
    PREPARED
}
```

Then created listener to change the States of my audioPlayer

```
private val prepareListener = MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener {
    Log.d("MyLog", "Media State = PREPARED")
    mediaState = MediaPlayerState.PREPARED
    
   }
private val onCompletedListener = MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener {
    Log.d("MyLog", "Media State = Completed")
    mediaState = MediaPlayerState.COMPLETED
   }
```

So, I was able to play media only when mediaState variable is on Prepared State

```
when(mediaState)
 {
   MediaPlayerState.COMPLETED, MediaPlayerState.PREPARED -> {

      mediaPlayer.start()
      mediaState = MediaPlayerState.PLAYING
     }
     ... 
     }
```

So when I release the media player, I changed the state to Idle

```
 override fun onDetachedFromWindow() {
    super.onDetachedFromWindow()
    mediaState = MediaPlayerState.IDLE
    mediaPlayer.release()
    Log.d("MyLog", "Media State = Released")

}
```

Then when I call  getCurrentPosition on media , I check for the state ( on background thread )

```
 if(mediaState == MediaPlayerState.PLAYING)
                seekBar.progress = mediaPlayer.currentPosition
```

Hence, No Illegal State Exception

By thinking in compose, changed the way of doing things..