# java.lang.illegalStateException when getting mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition and SeekBar going to Intial on Pause

Tags: java, android

I'm getting java.lang.IllegalStateException in my Android Music Player Application every time when I closes the Activity

```
                mCurrentPosition = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition()/1000; // In milliseconds
```

I've tried nearly all the codes available and even all at [java.lang.illegalStateException randomly occurs when getting mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37606726/java-lang-illegalstateexception-randomly-occurs-when-getting-mediaplayer-getcurr) also

Here's my Java code where I'm using it:

```
protected void initializeSeekBar(){
    mSeekBar.setMax(mediaPlayer.getDuration()/1000);

    mRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int mCurrentPosition;
            if(mediaPlayer!=null && mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
                mCurrentPosition = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition()/1000; // In milliseconds
            }
            else    {
                mCurrentPosition = 0;
            }

            if (mSeekBar != null)   {
                mSeekBar.setProgress(mCurrentPosition);
                getAudioStats();
            }
            handler.postDelayed(mRunnable,1000);
        }
    };
    handler.postDelayed(mRunnable,1000);
}
```

Please Help me out of this. Thanks in Advance

**Edit 1**
Also, my Seekbar goes to start when the music pauses and on play, it continues from where it was before pausing

```
mSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                getAudioStats();
                initializeSeekBar();

                if(mediaPlayer != null && fromUser) {
                    mediaPlayer.seekTo(progress * 1000);
                }


            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }
        });

protected void getAudioStats(){
        long duration  = mediaPlayer.getDuration()/1000; // In milliseconds
        long due = (mediaPlayer.getDuration() - mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition())/1000;
        long pass = duration - due;

        String test = DateUtils.formatElapsedTime(pass);
        String test1 = DateUtils.formatElapsedTime(due);

        current_time.setText("" + test);
        //mDuration.setText("" + duration + " seconds");
        total_time.setText("" + test1);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove your runnable from the handler queue when the activity closes (or, better yet, when it pauses). Try putting this in your activity's `onPause()` method:

```
handler.removeCallbacks(mRunnable);
```

For additional robustness, inside the runnable itself, you should only re-queue the runnable if the activity is still active. So instead of this:

```
handler.postDelayed(mRunnable,1000);
```

you should do this (assuming this code is in the activity class):

```
if (!isDestroyed()) {
    handler.postDelayed(mRunnable,1000);
}
```

Also make sure you are stopping the media player before the activity is destroyed.

P.S. If you call `initializeSeekBar()` multiple times, you will be reassigning `mRunnable` and leaving the old one in the handler queue where it can cause trouble later. To fix this, you should add this at the start of `initializeSeekBar()`:

```
protected void initializeSeekBar(){
    if (mRunnable != null) {
        handler.removeCallbacks(mRunnable);
    }
    // ... the rest of the method that you currently have
```

Comment: It's working but after playing some songs, it crashes again giving same exception on same line

Comment: @Anchit - Hm. Sounds like perhaps you have an orphaned runnable in the handler queue. I'll update my answer with a suggestion about fixing that.

Comment: Sure Sir, that would be highly appreciable